# How to change bitrate of a video using opencv python library

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, video-encoding, bitrate

I have to create a application in which I need to read a video and lower its bitrate to decrease the size of video.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to build OpenCV with the GStream Libraries, then you can do this for example:

```
cv2.VideoWriter("appsrc ! videoconvert ! avenc_mpeg4 bitrate=100000 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.mp4", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, 20.0, (1280,720))
```